# Buscar un dato de una tabla y colocar ese dato en otra ORACLE

Tags: sql, base-de-datos, oracle, select, insert

Tengo una tabla en una base de datos Oracle llamada **temporal**

```
CREATE TABLE temporal(
Nombre varchar(50),
Tipo varchar(50),
Pais varchar(50)
)
------Datos------
----------------------------------
Nombre     |  Tipo      | Pais
----------------------------------
User 1        2           USA
User 2        2           FRANCIA
User 3        1           ALEMANIA
User 4        2           FRANCIA
User 5        1           USA
```

Tengo otra tabla llamada **Pais**

```
CREATE TABLE PAIS(idpais int primary key,nombre varchar(50))
-------Datos------------
-------------------------
idpais      |   nombre
------------------------
   1              USA
   2             FRANCIA
   3             ALEMANIA
```

Y una tabla llamada **usuario** que se relaciona con la tabla **Pais**

```
CREATE TABLE Usuario(id int primary key,nombre varchar(50),pais int,
FOREIGN KEY(pais) REFERENCES Pais(idpais))
```

Yo inserto los datos del la tabla **temporal** en la tabla **Usuarios** *(id de la tabla Usuario es autonumerico asi que no lo necesito)*

```
INSERT INTO Usuario(nombre,pais)
SELECT  DISTINCT
t.nombre,

--Aqui es donde tengo el problema al insertar el pais

FROM temporal t
WHERE t.Nombre NOT IN (SELECT nombre FROM Usuario);
```

Yo quiero insertar el **idpais** pero solo tengo el nombre del pais

```
Select idpais From Pais Where nombre=t.pais
```

Quisiera que el int que da como resultado de esa consulta poder insertalo en la tabla **Usuario**

Answer (score 0):

La solución que veo es meter primero el usuario y luego hacer un UPDATE para introducir el País del mismo. Tal que así:

```
UPDATE Usuario SET                                                                 
pais=(SELECT idpais FROM PAIS WHERE PAIS.nombre=t.pais)         
WHERE Usuario.nombre=t.nombre;
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacer un *join* a la tabla `pais` en el `select`, en la línea de:

```
INSERT INTO Usuario(nombre, pais)
SELECT DISTINCT
         t.nombre
       , p.idPais
  FROM temporal t
       inner join Pais p on p.nombre = t.pais
 WHERE t.Nombre NOT IN (SELECT nombre FROM Usuario);
```